# IntelliSense dosen't give me option to select properties after implementing the LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Why IntelliSense dosen't give me option to select properties of the Glasses collection(i.e itemToDelete) after implimenting the LINQ.

Here is my C# LINQ:

```
public static void DeletePicturesFromHrdDisc(List<Glasses> Temp, int GlassID)
    {

        var itemToDelete = (from item in Temp
                            where item.GlassesID==GlassID
                            select item);     
         itemToDelete.(dosen't give me the optipn to select Properties of the Glasses class)
    }
```

here is my Glasses class:

```
 public class Glasses
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string SmalPicture { get; set; }
    public string BigPicture { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string FrameType { get; set; }
    public int GlassesID { get; set; }
    public string NameGlasses { get; set; }
    public string Collection { get; set; }
}
```

But I can see Glasses properties if i use .First() or .FirstorDefault() extensions as follows:

[image]

Any idea why can't I access the properties in the first version and why i see them in IntelliSense only if i use .First() or .FirstorDefault() extensions on my LINQ.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you apply Where/Select to Temp, you're not just getting a single result (there could be more than one result matching `where item.GlassesID==GlassID`, the compiler cannot be sure) so it does not return a single object instance of Glasses but an [IEnumerable<Glasses>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx). Simplified, think that you get a List<Glasses> back and you need to extract the actual object from the List before using its properties.

If you definitely know there's at most only one result returned, you can use [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) which returns the Glasses instance in the IEnumerable or null if it's empty, or [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) which returns the Glasses instance in the IEnumerable and throws an error if there isn't one. Both throw an exception if there is more than one result.

Using [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) would mean that if you accidentally get more than one result, you'll in this case get the first one, a random one. Perhaps not a good thing for an "itemToDelete", you'd probably want to know if your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

BTW, you can hover over `var` in Visual Studio to see the type of an expression.

In this case, `itemToDelete` is an `IEnumerable<Glasses>` of `Glasses` in `Temp` with a `GlassesID` of `GlassID`. Assuming your `GlassesID` is actually unique in `Temp`, it will only have one item which you can extract with `.Single()` or `.SingleOrDefault()`.

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out, `.Single()`, not `.First()` is the right method to use if you want to check for exactly one item.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ queries always produce a seqence of items, of type `IEnumerable<Glasses>` in your case. Even if there is only one element in the sequence, it is still a sequence. The sequence itself can only be enumerated, it does not have any other properties. To get at the elements' properties you first have to extract an element. That's exactly what `First()` does. It returns the first element of the sequence.

If your query always should produce exactly one item and any other result is an error you should use `Single()` instead of `First()`. If zero or one elements are acceptable you can use `SingleOrDefault()` and check the result for `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Because your first version is a collection of Glasses, not a Glasses object itself.  `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` return a single instance of Glasses, thus the properties are available.

Answer (score 1):

as the first() will give only a single item. so the compiler is giving intellisense for it.  as the 1st version is `IEnumerable<Glasses>` so it has collection of objects. you need to iterate it.

```
 var itemToDelete = (from item in Temp
                       where item.GlassesID==GlassID
                       select item);     

foreach(var i in itemToDelete )
{
   i.SomeProperty // do some thing with i ;
}
```

Comment: Minor, but important nitpick: the LINQ query returns `IEnumerable<Glasses>`, not `List<Glasses>`. It's not important in this case, but in general the computation is redone every time you iterate over it; to you have to explicitly call `.ToList()` to get `List<Glasses>`.